# How to access a value in a table connected by a Foreign Key

Tags: python, django, database, mysql-python

Currently I have a table called `Load` that has a relationship to a table called `Container` through a Foreign Key called `Container_ID` (the FK is just an integer). The foreign key lives in the `Load` table. Each row in the `Load` table has a `Container_ID`.

The table `Container` has a column called `Container_Name`.

What I want to do is to grab all rows from the Load table, and be able to tell what the actual container name is. **Not** the `Container_ID`, but the `Container_Name` that's in the `Container` table.

I tried doing something like `var = Load.objects.values_list('container_ID')` but that only returns the actual foreign key integer, and I'm not sure how to take it that one step further to dive into the actual Container table to grab that Container_Name field.

Just for clarification, I am working with Python and MYSQL here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the Container name through field lookup. You can see it
[here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#:%7E:text=Blog.objects.values(%27name%27%2C%20%27entry__headline%27)) in the docs. In your example, you can access it as `var=Load.objects.values_list('container__Container_Name')`
The generic syntax for this is `var=ModelName.objects.value_list('foreign_key_field__field_in_related_table')`